# How to Download a File Using Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

How can I download a file using Internet Explorer (or any other browser) on Windows Phone 7.5 Mango, and save it to my phone. Currently it just opens the file. Is there a way to save it instead?

Comment: What type of files are you trying to download? You can click on a download link (e.g. zip) and it will download it. Whether or not you can do anything with the downloaded file is another story.

Comment: Well. Thanks for your reply. I am trying to download mp3 & video file but its getting directly played so I can't save that file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I Have found a software that can download videos for u which **MediaDownloader** Here is the link for that http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/media-downloader/d5484913-8bfd-477a-bc96-b3aa2e9dcee1

Now with Windows Phone 7.10.8XXXX u can even transfer files via Bluetooth.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot download media files using the browser. The browser will only allow you to stream them and will not allow you to save them to your media library.

You can download Office files, text, images and Zip archives (as long as the archive contains supported types).

Source: [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpfeatures/how-to-download-a-file-in-windows-phone-7-on/bb80f92b-6111-4d17-8bcb-3a4c65d9006e), [WPCentral](http://forums.wpcentral.com/os-discussion/178813.htm) and [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1536615) forums.

Comment: @RickJackson And Office files (and pdf) will show in Office hub in "documents".

Answer (score 2):

You can download any file  using [UC Browser](http://www.ucweb.com/ucbrowser/download/) also you can share videos, music etc through bluetooth also .

Answer (score -3):

you can download file using internet explore and UC browsebhr there are the many way to download file .you access internet and open as you like and download it